# Can't add Ado .Net Entity Data Model

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm doing these steps:

1. Create new vs2010 C# console application
2. Project menu -> Add New Item
3. select Ado.NET Entity Data Model -> click Add
4. Entity Data Model wizard window opened.
5. Select Generate From database -> Click Next
6. The next window appears for less than 1 second and it gets closed automatically.

I tried to reset vs2010 setting but no good news, the problem still exist.

I also tried it with ASP.NET Website.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem and finally fixed it by deleting

`c:\users\myusername\appdata\roaming\microsoft\visualstudio\10.0\SeverExplorer\DefaultView.SEView`.

Comment: Seems it works by deleting all your server explorer connections/settings. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can resolved this fix:

1. in the route C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ServerExplorer
2. delete the file "DefaultView.SEView"
3. press keys window + R-> and write devenv.exe /ResetSettings
4. And Open Visual Studio